# mouse wheel to be use for swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function which works for mouse wheel and i want to use the same function for swipe.

```
// Mouse Wheel support 
this.MouseWheel =
{   
    init: function()
    {
        // Init mouse wheel listener 
        if(window.addEventListener)
        {
            my.ImageFlowDiv.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', my.MouseWheel.get, false);
        }
        my.Helper.addEvent(my.ImageFlowDiv,'mousewheel',my.MouseWheel.get);
    },

    get: function(event)
    {
        var delta = 0;
        if (!event)
        {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (event.wheelDelta)
        {
            delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        }
        else if (event.detail)
        {
            delta = -event.detail / 3;
        }
        if (delta)
        {
            my.MouseWheel.handle(delta);
        }
        my.Helper.suppressBrowserDefault(event);
    },

    handle: function(delta)
    {
    alert('handle called');
        var change = false;
        var newImageID = 0;
        if(delta > 0)
        {
            if(my.imageID >= 1)
            {
                newImageID = my.imageID -3;
                change = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(my.imageID < (my.max-1))
            {
                newImageID = my.imageID +4;
                change = true;
            }
        }

        /* Glide to next (mouse wheel down) / previous (mouse wheel up) image  */
        if(change)
        {
        //alert('new image id='+newImageID);
            my.glideOnEvent(newImageID);
        }
    }
};
```

Earlier i used the `touchswipe` plugin and it was working fine but i want to use another plugin as `touchswipe` is disturbing touch support.

```
$("#imageFlow").swipe({
  swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
    alert('swipe called');
    if(direction == 'left') {
      my.MouseWheel.handle(-1);
    } else if (direction == 'right') {
      my.MouseWheel.handle(1);
    }       
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Hammer JS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)? I find their syntax is fairly simple to use and does not interfere with my other touch events.

Your code could then look similar to this:

```
Hammer($('#imageFlow')).on("swipe", function(event) {
        console.log('swipe called'); //(instead of alert)
        if (event.gesture.direction === 'left'){
           my.MouseWheel.handle(-1);
        } else if (event.gesture.direction === 'right'){
           my.MouseWheel.handle(1);
        };
    });
```

In the [docs](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started)

**Also bear in mind to use 3 equals signs in JavaScript. so:**

`if (myName === 'Jean-Marie'){//dostuff}`

instead of

`if (myName == 'Jean-Marie'){//dostuff}`

Comment: You don't have to use 3 equal signs. That is if you want to ensure they are the same values and of the same type. For instance `1 == "1"` is true but `1 === "1"` is not true. But when comparing two string they are the same thing. But if you know 'myName' is string in the above example then the `===` is pointless. Here is  another example when you will need to use them: `1==true` evaluates to `true` but  `1===true` evaluates to false.

Comment: @DutGRIFF you should always use`===` because. the unique way you can use `==` is to check if value valu is null or undefined by compare with `if(val == null){ ... }` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Sameness http://blog.boyet.com/blog/javascriptlessons/javascript-an-acceptable-use-of-double-equals-just/

Comment: @Yukulélé I don't think `===` is necessary with strings. I do see that it can save you some trouble later if you use `===` when comparing other things. I guess it is good practice to use `===` as much as possible but as far as I can tell it will not make a difference here. Thanks for the info.